# Compile another java file from java file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-6, java-5

Just out of curiosity. Can we compile  & run a java file from another java program? 
If so, can you send a reference to that knowledge source?

Comment: Here is a link that explains how to invoke the compiler from inside your Java code:

http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip131.html?page=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Java Compiler Api](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javac/index.html) and [this](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/73-the-java-60-compiler-api-1.html) little example.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the java source code already in a file, then you can just call the java compiler.  The java compiler is built-in to the JVM libraries as of version 1.6.

[The interface is documented here.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)

Answer (score 1):

Didn't read it thoroughly, but maybe [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2006/jw-0612-dynamic.html?page=5) helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 6, the best way to do this is through the [`javax.tools.JavaCompiler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) interface.

If you're using an older version of Java, you must call `javac` directly using `Runtime.exec()`, then load the class data by subclassing `ClassLoader` and overriding `findClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but you need java compiler and not only java runtime. First you generate your source, save it and then use Dynamic class loading(tutorial http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use javac (JDK is needed):
http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip131.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by calling the cmd prompt or use the Main class from the Java Code.

I don't know remember well how is it, but I did it a long time ago.